# what is the correct method to print this image?

Tags: python

I'm trying to print the following image via python

```
print("""
            ____
          .\    /
          |\\  //\
         /  \\//  \
        /   /  \   \
       /   /    \   \
      /   /      \   \  
     /   /______^ \   \
    /    ________\ \   \
   /   /            \   \
 /\\  /              \  //\
/__\\_\              /_//__\
""")

input()
```

output

```
        ____
      .\    /
      |\  //         /  \//          /   /  \          /   /    \         /   /      \   \  
 /   /______^ \       /    ________\ \      /   /            \    /\  /              \  ///__\_\              /_//__
```

hope someone can help me solve this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Backslashes escape the newlines, change it to a raw string with `r"..."`:

```
print(r"""
            ____
          .\    /
          |\\  //\
         /  \\//  \
        /   /  \   \
       /   /    \   \
      /   /      \   \  
     /   /______^ \   \
    /    ________\ \   \
   /   /            \   \
 /\\  /              \  //\
/__\\_\              /_//__\
""")

input()
```